# Solr - trouble getting Java to run

Tags: java, solr, django-haystack

I'm trying to get started with Solr, but it appears that Java cannot be found. I have JRE installed at `/home/bill/jre1.6.0_31`. But based on the Solr tutorial it sound like I don't even need to access that. See excerpt from the tutorial below:

> Solr can run in any Java Servlet container of your choice, but to simplify this tutorial, the example index includes a small installation of Jetty.
>
> To launch Jetty with the Solr WAR, and the example configs, just run the start.jar ...

When I do this I get the following:

```
bill@ubuntu:/home/~solr/apache-solr-3.6.0/example$ java -jar start.jar

The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:

 * gcj-4.4-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * cacao
 * gij-4.3
 * jamvm

Try: sudo apt-get install   -- 'selected package'
```

I already have JRE installed and obviously don't want to install more.

Comment: do a which java and let me know what do you get , seems yo are having only gcj not jdk
thanks update: please run this command on $prompt which java and see if you actually have jdk installed or only jre Thanks

Comment: bill@ubuntu:/home/~solr/apache-solr-3.6.0/example$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode  ... I mapped a search path to my JRE. but when I try to start localhost:8983 I get a big fat Error 500 - 'severe errors in solr coniguration",  I'm trying to figure that one out now.

Answer (score 2):

Run these first:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sun-java-community-team/sun-java6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

These will install JDK and then you can run solr.

Comment: went through the steps above, but still not getting Solr.  It does not seem like the jdk got fully installed.  I do have a jre installed at /home/mydir/jre1.6.0_31, I'm not sure if this is a good loction for it.  Would like to get rid of any old Java stuff but I'm a little hesitant to start trashing directories.  Any advise is appreciated.  Also was wondering if I need to symlink from my solr/example dir to a jre directory.